# Having problems to add SSL to nuxt-axios web app on DOCKER

Tags: docker, ssl, axios, nuxt.js, caddy

Well after many tests and brain burns trying with nginx, caddy and other resources to apply SSL I resort to this medium.

all the services are running on docker container.

I can't fully apply the certificates, rather I can't get my site to work with SSL, I can get to the login with https but then I can't get past that barrier:

to formalize:
https://example.com:3000/login (basic web domain)
https://example.com:3001/api (all my resources)

for https i have to change the axios BASEurl form: (recomendations from caddy forum)
this: http://example.com:3001/api
to this: https://example.com/api

to stop having the error of ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

I share my settings from my last failed attempt with caddy.
The truth is that at this point I don't know if it is a bad configuration problem on the caddy side or on the node-nuxt-axios side.

caddyfile:

```
{
 debug
}

example.com {

    handle_path /api/* {
        reverse_proxy /api/* node:3001
    }

    handle {
        reverse_proxy node:3000
    }
}

emqx.example.com {
    reverse_proxy emqx:18083
}
ws.example.com {
    reverse_proxy emqx:8083
}
wss.example.com {
    reverse_proxy emqx:8084
}

portainer.example.com {

   reverse_proxy portainer:9000
 
}
```

here it goes nuxt.config.js

```
  axios: {
    baseURL: process.env.AXIOS_BASE_URL
  },
  env: {
    mqtt_prefix: process.env.MQTT_PREFIX,
    mqtt_host: process.env.MQTT_HOST,
    mqtt_port: process.env.MQTT_PORT
  },

  server: {
    https: true,
    port: 3000,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
  },

  serverMiddleware: {
    https: true,
    '/api': '~/api'
  },
```

here is the index.js for api

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");
const colors = require("colors");
const app = express();
require("dotenv").config();


//express config
app.use(morgan("tiny"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true,
})
);


app.use(cors());

app.use("/api", require("./routes/devices.js"));
app.use("/api", require("./routes/users.js"));
app.use("/api", require("./routes/templates.js"));
app.use("/api", require("./routes/datas.js"));
app.use("/api", require("./routes/webhooks.js"));
app.use("/api", require("./routes/emqxapi.js"));
app.use("/api", require("./routes/alarms.js"));
app.use("/api", require("./routes/controls.js")); // nueva funcion
app.use("/api", require("./routes/dataprovider.js"));

module.exports = app;

//listener
app.listen(process.env.API_PORT, () => {
  console.log("API server listening on port " + process.env.API_PORT);
}); //api port 3001
```

for the record all services works like a charm on http, but having problems with secure comunication.